# Django - How To Display Model's Choices as Checkboxes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147752/in-django-is-there-a-way-to-display-choices-as-checkboxes) but I am still unable to display CHOICES as checkboxes on my form.

models.py

```
class Car(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
       ('s', 'small'),
       ('m', 'medium'),
       ('b', 'big'),
     )
     type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxSelectMultiple

from cars.models import Car

class AddCar(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Car.TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `forms.RadioSelect()` instead of `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()` since its single valued.

To override widgets for ModelForm, [check the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)

```
class AddCar(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        widgets = {'type': forms.RadioSelect}
```

Or as in your question, the `type` line should be above the `class Meta` line, inside `AddCar`

```
class AddCar(forms.ModelForm):
    type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Car.SCENERY_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

Comment: He CAN use a checkbox input. Should use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxInput). So in your example sould use:
`widgets = {'type': forms.CheckboxInput}`

Comment: @marianobianchi I'm afraid he can't, the `CheckboxInput` widget is used for boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Route.SCENERY_CHOICES` not `Car.TYPE_CHOICES`

Answer (score 0):

thats for the forms.forms

```
class AddCarForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

thats for the forms.ModelForm

```
class AddCar(forms.ModelForm):
    type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

then in template which is very important to use this

```
{{ form.type }}
```

i.e dont call `type` as html like `<input type="checkbox" name="type" id="id_type">`

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use multiple select, without using any custom field, this is what I have done in a similar scenario.
Warning: The value stored in database violates the normal form. But as it is supposed to be 2-3 value string(with very slim chances to grow, I preferred this quick hack)

What I did, is that the model only uses a CharField, without bothering about, what it is going to be used for. ModelForm, on the other end, handles the multiple choice logic.

In my "models.py"

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    platforms = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
```

In "forms.py"

```
class NotificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = models.Notification

    platforms = forms.MultipleChoiceField(initial='android', choices=(('ios', 'iOS'), ('android', 'Android')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs['instance']
        # Intercepting the instance kw arg, and turning it into a list from a csv string.
        if instance is not None:
            instance.platforms = instance.platforms.split(",")
            kwargs['instance'] = instance

        super(NotificationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do other stuff

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NotificationForm, self).clean()
        platforms = cleaned_data['platforms']
        # Convert the list back into a csv string before saving
        cleaned_data['platforms'] = ",".join(platforms)
        # Do other validations
        return cleaned_data
```

The data stored in database column would be a string "ios,android" if both checkboxes are selected. Otherwise, it would be 'ios', 'android'. As I said, certainly not normalized. And things may actually turn ugly if your field can have many values some day.