# How to implement a bitmask in a Django choice field

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
User:
    name
    role
```

And it can take the following values for its role:

- editor
- supervisor
- consultant

And since the user can have one, two or all the roles, I chose to implement this feature in the form of a bitmask, where a role can take the following values:

- editor: 1
- supervisor: 2
- consultant: 4

Or any combination of them:

```
editor and consultant: 5 # (permission bits 1+4)
```

Of course if I want to know wether the user has a certain role bit set, I can just call its `has_role` method:

```
def has_role(self, role):
    return not self.role & role is 0
```

However, I don't know what Django widget I can use or how to make one for this purpose, the only thing I know is that I can use a the choices keyword on the model's field to limit its options, but it won't let me combine more than one option.

How can I implement this?

The model looks as follows:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ROLES = (
        (1, 'editor'),
        (2, 'supervisor'),
        (4, 'consultant'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLES)

    def has_role(self, role):
        return not self.role & role is 0
```

I am using django 1.9 and python 3.5

Comment: Can you not create a collection of checkboxes, one for each role and then read which are active?

Comment: Of course I can, can you elaborate on how can I create said collection?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not knowledgable on Django yet. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147752/in-django-is-there-a-way-to-display-choices-as-checkboxes) close enough for your purposes?

Comment: That would do the trick, let me check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need a bitmask here? The usual approach in Django would be to create 3 boolean fields instead.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_consultant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Of course this works, but I wanted some way to specify the options and concentrate them in one field of the model, so I can add new elements to the bitmask transparently.

Comment: If you want to add roles dynamically, then a separate model with a many to many field would be a typical approach. You can use the `Group` model from `django.contrib.auth` for this.